# Precedence of limits formulas

Tags: limits

**Problem:**

> $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ln(x+h)+ln(x-h)-2lnx}{h^2}, x>0$

**Solution:**

> $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{2lnx+ln(1+\frac{h}{x})+ln(1-\frac{h}{x})-2lnx}{h^2}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ln(1+\frac{h}{x})+ln(1-\frac{h}{x})}{h^2}$

**Version 1:**
considering that $\lim_{h\to 0} ln(1+\frac{h}{x})=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h}{x}$ and $\lim_{h\to 0} ln(1-\frac{h}{x})=-\frac{h}{x}$ then

> $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{h}{x}-\frac{h}{x}}{h^2}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{0}{h^2}=0$

**Version 2:** considering that $ln(1+\frac{h}{x})+ln(1-\frac{h}{x})=ln(1-\frac{h^2}{x^2})$ then

> $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ln(1-\frac{h^2}{x^2})}{h^2}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{-\frac{h^2}{x^2}}{h^2}=-\frac{1}{x^2}$

Which version, and why, is correct?

Comment: Version 1 is incorrect, since it should be written $\frac{O(h^2)}{h^2}$. The second one is correct instead.

Comment: Hello @Crostul. Could you tell me more about $\frac{O(h^2)}{h^2}$ please?

Comment: Well, in your first version you are using an approximation. But that approximation is too rough. You need $\ln (1+ \frac{h}{x}) = \frac{h}{x} - \frac{h^2}{2x^2} + o(h^2)$, where $o(h^2)$ denotes some remainder which goes to $0$ faster than $h^2$.

Comment: Wow Excellent @Crostul , please apply your comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\ln(x+h)+\ln(x-h)-2\ln(x)}{h^2}=$$

---

Apply l'Hôpital's rule, to get:

---

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{1}{x+h}-\frac{1}{x-h}}{2h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{(h-x)(h+x)}=\frac{1}{(0-x)(0+x)}=-\frac{1}{x^2}$$

Comment: Hi @Jan Eerland. Please note that I'd like to know which version is correct and why, and not the solution for the problem.

Comment: @Ilo Your second method is right!